# Invoke Coffeescript during Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, capybara

My app has quite a few different places where I update the database by calling ajax functions when the user clicks a button/link/div. I need to include these features in my tests, but I don't yet know enough about Capybara.

Below is an example of one div that I want to test, the associated ajax call, and the test that I would like to pass. I should add that I'm building through Cloud9 IDE, in case that makes a difference.

**View**

```
<% @seminar.students.order(:last_name).in_groups_of(6).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
        <% group.each do |student| %>
            <% if student %>
               <% this_ss = @seminar.seminar_students.find_by(:user => student) %>
                  <% if this_ss.present %>
                       <% thisClass = "col-md-2 seat clickySeat" %>
                       <% thisText = "Present" %>
                  <% else %>
                       <% thisClass = "col-md-2 seat clickySeat absent" %>
                       <% thisText = "Absent" %>
                  <% end %>
                  <div class = "<%= thisClass %>" id="<%= this_ss.id %>" name="ss_<%= this_ss.id %>">
                      <%= student.first_plus_init %><br/>
                      <p class="presentTag"><%= thisText %></p>
                  </div>
               <% end %>
         <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Coffeescript**

```
if $('.clickySeat').length > 0
    $('.clickySeat').on "click", ->
        this_tag = $(this).find(".presentTag")
        seminar_student_id = $(this).attr('id')
        url = '/seminar_students/'+seminar_student_id
        if this_tag.text() == "Absent"
            attendance = true
            $(this).removeClass("absent")
            this_tab.text("Present")
        else
            attendance = false
            $(this).addClass("absent")
            this_tab.text("Absent")
        $.ajax
            type: "PUT",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json"
            data:
                seminar_student:
                    present: attendance
```

**Test**

```
test "attendance with click" do
    @ss = @student_3.seminar_students.find_by(:seminar => @seminar)
    assert @ss.present

    capybara_login(@teacher_1)
    click_on("desk_consult_#{@seminar.id}")
    click_on("#{new_consultancy_button_text}")
    find("##{@ss.id}").click

    assert_not @ss.present
    click_on("Create Desk Consultants Groups")
end
```

In development and production, the divs and ajax are working to toggle students being marked absent/present in the database. But in testing, the line assert_not @ss.present fails. This is the pattern that I'm trying to fix everywhere: none of my capybara tests are invoking any javascript.

I've read through a few similar questions and the related articles. I've tried all suggestions that I've read so far, such as adding the selenium-webkit gem so that I can use the line Capybara.javascript-driver = :selenium. No solutions that I've encountered so far have worked for me.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: You don't tell us what actually fails about the test you want to pass.  Also, when you set `Capybara.javascript_driver` it's only used by tests you specify to use the javascript capable driver. See - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver.  You should be able to tell whether or not it's using selenium since it would generally open an instance of Firefox or Chrome (depending on your configuration).

Comment: Aha. Good point. The test fails on the line assert_not @ss.present.  In development and production, clicking the div updates the database to toggle the student between absent and present. In testing, nothing happens.

Comment: This is the pattern that I'm trying to fix everywhere: none of my capybara tests are invoking any javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your tests running JS is generally one of two problems, and then there are two further issues with your test that would probably cause failure beyond that.

For the JS issue, the first cause could be that you have an error in one of your JS assets which causes them not to be processed when concatenated together.  Since you state it works in production mode (where concatenation also occurs) we should be able to rules this out.  The second cause would be that you're not running with a JS capable driver.  Make sure you have followed the instructions from the README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitest - are deriving your test classes from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest and that the last part of that section (where Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver) is being run before any tests that require JS.  (If you want all your tests to run with JS support you can just set Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver after setting Capybara.javascript_driver).  If using Rails < 5.1 you'll probably also need to install and configure database_cleaner - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup

That should get your tests running with a JS capable driver - beyond that -
 First: When you call `find(...).click` that is not guaranteed to wait for any actions caused by the click to complete.  This means you need to set an assertion (one of the Capybara provided assertions since they have waiting/retrying behavior) for a visible change triggered by the click to ensure it has completed before attempting to access an element from the database.
Second: since you've already loaded `@ss` it's not going to reflect a change in DB state until you reload the object.

Together that means your test will need to change along the lines of

```
test "attendance with click" do
  @ss = @student_3.seminar_students.find_by(:seminar => @seminar)
  assert @ss.present

  capybara_login(@teacher_1)
  click_on("desk_consult_#{@seminar.id}")
  click_on("#{new_consultancy_button_text}")
  find("##{@ss.id}").click
  assert_text("You are marked as absent") # An assertion for whatever visible change occurs due to the previous click which will delay the next statement until the app has completed processing
  assert_not @ss.reload.present # Need to reload the object to see any DB changes
  click_on("Create Desk Consultants Groups") 
end
```

The need to reload objects all the time is part of the reason that doing assertions on DB objects is generally frowned upon, and you should mainly just be testing the UI behavior/changes (in feature tests)

Comment: I think that I've implemented all of your suggestions. Now it seems the code in the testing file cannot access fixtures. If I place "debugger" in the testing file, User.count returns zero. (Is this because database_cleaner has "cleaned" out all of the data?) To work around, I tried creating a new teacher at the beginning of the test. Unfortunately, this newly-created teacher cannot login. When "debugger" is placed in my sessions_controller, User.count returns all 124 users from the fixtures. But it doesn't include the teacher that I created in the test.

Comment: When I try it without the cleaner, I get this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked:

Comment: @JeffZivkovic You haven't clarified what version of Rails you're using, but if using < 5.1 (database_cleaner isn't required in 5.1+) and you're not able to access records created in your tests then it most likely means you haven't correctly enabled database_cleaner to use truncation or deletion mode when running the JS capable tests, and are instead still using transaction mode.

Comment: Excellent! Yes. The database_cleaner strategy was the key. Although, the desired strategy was the reverse of your suggestion. The only strategy that got my test green was "transaction". But this strategy seems to have eliminated the need to create a new teacher within the test. I appreciate your continuous help throughout these past few days. Have a wonderful holiday!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) driver and change the configurations to work with it. Don't forget to have PhantomJS on your path (you can install it with the command: `npm install -g phantomjs`.

You should add the `js: true` on some part of your test, I just don't remember where. But, you can search about it. =]

Good luck.

Comment: `js: true` only works when using RSpec -- the OP appears to be using minitest.

Comment: If I can figure out how to install phantomjs, will it work with Minitest? Does using Cloud9 IDE make a difference?